# How to send objects from node.js to front end javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, frontend, render

In Node.js, while rendering an HTML page, I'm sending an object. How will I access that particular object into my front end javascript.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please include code that shows what you're trying to do and include information about what you're using to render your HTML pages and show us what object you're trying to send.  FYI, you don't send objects directly.  Instead, you send some representation of the object that can be converted back into an object on the other end.  The JSON text format is commonly used for this.  That capability might be built into your renderer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `EJS` then here's the answer

in backend render the response like this, enter the path of your ejs file. and pass whatever data you want to as the next argument

```
response.render(".path/to/ejs/file", {data: data});
```

In frontend, access it like this

```
<%- data %>
```

for more info you can check this project

[NodeJS Boiler Plate](https://github.com/Atishay96/boiler_plate/)